# Ubercart attribute changes price without page reload on Drupal 7

Tags: 7, ubercart

Running Drupal 7, and the latest stable UB. Currently, each product's price is set to $0. We have attributes that get selected and that is what determines a product final price. When a user selects the attribute. We want it to automatically change the product price without a page reload or needing to add it to the cart. How can I accomplish this?

Update: This is the latest [patch](http://drupal.org/files/1380772-43-attribute-ajax.patch) that was mentioned [here](http://drupal.org/node/1380772#comment-6320250). I have patched my code as follows. I attached a pastebin of the patched code for review in case I missed something. Also if anyone wants post-patch code prior to it getting released to dev.

- http://pastebin.com/FnKCrYGk - uc_attribute.module
- http://pastebin.com/f2GN5Ms9 - uc_order.order_pane.inc
- http://pastebin.com/1AURsfML - uc_product.admin.inc
- http://pastebin.com/i5JF3dif - uc_product.module
- http://pastebin.com/7VnGKQap - uc_product_kit.module

Some people report that the patch works. I unfortunately haven't been able to get it to work. The blue spinning ajax icon shows like its doing something but my display price doesn't change.

UPDATE FIX!: This [thread](http://drupal.org/node/1380772#comment-6325184) details the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is planned to be included in Ubercart itself, see http://drupal.org/node/1380772 - any tests or comments are welcome in that issue.

Comment: Will be adding the latest patches and report back on here and on the Drupal forums.

Comment: Just tested with the latest patch. Ajax Icon spins like if its doing something but it doesn't modify my Display Price. Posted on the Drupal Forum as well.

Comment: @DigitalFire Do you know if this same functionality is available in Ubercart 2/Drupal 6? 
------ 
 Never mind, found a solution for D6/UC2: http://drupal.org/project/uc_aac